# About the convergence and divergence of the following integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, divergent-series

[image]

I have these two integral and wanted to know how I can explain their convergence and divergence by using comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

First integral diverges, because the integrand goes as $1/(1-w)$ as $w \to 1^-$.  This is a non-integrable singularity.  In fact, at a pole $w_0$, if the integrand goes as $1/(w-w_0)^a$ as $w \to w_0$, then we have convergence only if $a < 1$.

Second integral converges because, at the pole $\alpha_2$, the integrand goes as $1/(\alpha_2-w)^{1/2}$ as $w \to \alpha_2^-$, unless $\alpha_1 \lt 0$ and $\alpha_2 \gt 0$, in which case it diverges.

Comment: For the first integral are you comparing it with 1/(1-w) to show its divergence? If yes, can you please tell me for what value of W you are making this comparison?

Comment: @Kiran: Yes, I am comparing the integrand with $1/(1-w)$ for values of $w$ near $1$.

Comment: you mean \sqrt((w-alpha^2)(w-1/alpha^2))/w(1-w) > 1/1-w   for w<1?

Comment: @Kiran: no.  I mean that the integrand is greater than some constant (not necessarily one) times $1/(1-w)$ as $w \to 1$, and because the latter diverges, the integral diverges.

Comment: yes but we wanted to prove this divergence by comparison test and in comparison test we will compare the integrals. Then we must define W since  \sqrt((w-alpha^2)(w-1/alpha^2))/w(1-w) > 1/1-w is not true for all real value of W. Can you explain it more thanks